# Efficiency of timeout on Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that sends emails every time a new element is added to the db, like so:

```
export const onWorkCreation = functions.database.ref('/Works/{workId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const work = snapshot.val();
    // const emails = ['email1@email.com', 'email2@email.com', 'email3@email.com'];
    // TODO sprawdz z jakiej kategorii zadanie, wyslij do uzytkownikow ktorzy maja te kategorie + link do deaktywacji emaili.
    let calls = [];
    const persons = admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('userType').equalTo('person').once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(err => console.log(1, err));
    const companies = admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('userType').equalTo('company').once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(err => console.log(2, err));
    const undefineds = admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('userType').equalTo('undefined').once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(err => console.log(3, err));
    calls.push(persons, companies, undefineds);

    let users = await Promise.all(calls).catch(err => console.log(4, err));
    users = [...arrayFromObject(users[0]), ...arrayFromObject(users[1]), ...arrayFromObject(users[2])];
    users.filter(u => u.receivesNotifications === undefined || u.receivesNotifications === true);
    const usersIds = [];
    for (const i in users) {
        const user = users[i];
        if (user.testInfo[work.category] !== undefined && user.testInfo[work.category.toLowerCase()].status.toLowerCase() === 'approved' && user.receivesNotifications !== false) {
            usersIds.push(user.id);
        } else {
            // console.log(work);
            // console.log(user.testInfo[work.category]);
            // console.log(work.category);
            // console.log(2, user.testInfo[work.category] !== undefined, 3, user.testInfo[work.category] !== undefined && user.testInfo[work.category.toLowerCase()].status.toLowerCase() === 'approved', 4, user.receivesNotifications !== false)
        }
    }
    calls = [];
    for (const i in usersIds) {
        calls.push(0);
        try {
            calls[i] = await admin.auth().getUser(usersIds[i]).then(r => r).catch(err => console.log(5, err, usersIds[i]));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('user', usersIds[i]);
        }
    }
    users = await Promise.all(calls).catch(err => console.log(6, err));
    users = arrayFromObject(users);
    console.log('users', users);
    const usersDetails = [];
    for (const i in users) {
        const user = {
            email: users[i].email,
            id: users[i].uid,
        };
        usersDetails.push(user);
    }
    calls = [];
    const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'USER',
            pass: 'PASS'
        },
    });
    for (const i in usersDetails) {
        const user = usersDetails[i];
        calls.push(mailTransport.sendMail({
            from: `ZdajTo <noreply@zdajto.com>`,
            to: user.email,
            subject: `Dostepne sa nowe zadania!`,
            html: `<p>Hej! Sprawdz aplikacje ZdajTo! Dostepne sa nowe zadania z kategorii ${work.category}! Aby zrezygnowac z otrzymywania emaili kliknij w <a href="https://us-central1-uczsieapp.cloudfunctions.net/adminHelper/cancelEmailSubscription/${user.id}" target="_blank">ten link</a></p>`,
        }).then(() => null).catch(err => console.log(7, err, user.email)));
    }
    return Promise.all(calls).then(() => console.log('Emails sent')).catch(err => console.log(8, err));
});
```

It is a lot of code, but what it does in short is just grab emails for certain users and send emails to these addresses.

Now. I am firing it up every time a new work child is created. Is there a way of checking if the child was hanging in the db for more then 5 mins?

What I want to achieve:

If the `work`'s property (`available`) is not changed in 5 mins, I want to send the emails again. I could achieve it by firing up a timeout loop, but I was hoping there would be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I'd use a CRON function that queries work based upon the status and createTime. (You'll want to populate the createTime value when you add the work element.) The easiest way to execute CRON functions is with Azure Functions, but, you may also look at other options native to GCP/firebase.